# Comparing two lists for partial id in the text

Tags: excel-formula

I have two lists, one of the list contains inputs like these:

- Description1 (id)
- Description2 (id2)
- Description3 (id3)

other list is again like these:

- Descriptionx (id)
- Descriptiony (id2)
- Descriptionz (id3)

What I need to is compare them and show a new list with non existing ids in the second list. The descriptions could be different, the id locations could be different also there are some with additional parenthesis like this:

- Description (id)(other info)

So I need to exclude those other info from id comparison also.

Would VLOOKUP help me with what I want? If it is how could I use it for partial match?

Here is a [sample file](https://gofile.io/?c=HU6EQO) to explain what I mean.. The data is randomized, but I matched some ids in the parenthesis on the A and B columns, the C column should only list the ids not existing in B column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, based on your picture, this would be the formula: **ARRAY FORMULA: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$77,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(MID($A$1:$A$77,SEARCH("(",$A$1:$A$77)+1,SEARCH(")",$A$1:$A$77)-SEARCH("(",$A$1:$A$77)-1),MID($B$1:$B$57,SEARCH("(",$B$1:$B$57)+1,SEARCH(")",$B$1:$B$57)-SEARCH("(",$B$1:$B$57)-1),0)),ROW($A$1:$A$77)),ROW(A1)))
```

This creates a list of the missing ID's of list 1 in list 2. Be careful with `ROW($A$1:$A$4)` as it has to be the same length as the search list and needs to start at row 1. `ROW(A1)` needs to start at row one.

If you want a list of all matching id's just change `ISERROR` to `ISNUMBER`.

Comment: so if I have two lists in Sheet1, and Sheet2's  A column, what would be the formula in Sheet3's A column?

Comment: Tried but as soon as I hit enter it says there's something wrong with formula, the sheets name are the same, and just for testing I left A2:A5 etc, and didn't use the entire list, but the result is still the same.

Comment: OK, next try. This was created with your sample data. The sheet was really helpful. I had just 4 hits

Comment: Now, I see the problem. I'm using Mac version of Excel, it seems it doesn't like "," between parameters. When I change it to ";" it works.

Comment: Well, I don't know about the mac version, but I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use iferror() and vlookup() like this:

[image]

This, at least, will give you something to start with, you can develop it how you wish.

Comment: the ids are in the same field, so this doesn't work for my question. For this to work I need to implement another formula so the id is separated.

Comment: @Plato so provide some data showing clearly your input and expected outputs.

Comment: @Plato update your question with the data, posting links and further info in comments is not helpful to others reading your question.

Comment: Data is confidential so I cannot share it here.. But I think the explanation is clear enough.

Comment: @Plato you can change names etc to anonymize the data, a common practice on here.